# Converting CSV timestamp to postgresql timestamp format gives Error: date/time field value out of range

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I am trying to import a csv file with Timestamp `(2020/01/07 07:20:12.718000)` into postgresql. As far i have gathered from other posts, I cannot import the timestamp directly as Postgresql Timestamp format. I have to import the csv timestamp as text, then convert into postgresql format.

So far, I was able to import all the timestamp using the copy command. Then, I tried using the following codes to convert the timestamp format:

```
Attempt1
select (to_timestamp(mytable."Timestamp",'HH24:MI:SS.MS')) as newtimestamp from mytable;

Attempt2
select (to_timestamp(mytable."Timestamp",'HH24:MI:SS.FM.US')) as newtimestamp from mytable;
```

Both gave the `Error:date/time field value out of range`
I thought the issue might be because of the millisecond precision of 6 digits. To handle 6 digits millisecond precision, my attempt2 should have been sufficient.

Now i am not sure what to do.
I am using postgresql 12.

```
show datestyle;
 DateStyle 
-----------
 ISO, MDY
```

Please guide me in the right direction. Also, if there is a better way of importing timestamp from csv to postgresql,please let me know. 
Thank you

Comment: I'm a bit lost.  You have a string that starts with a date.  However, you are not converting the date?  In other words your format and string are different.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can just hard-cast that to timestamp:

```
$ psql -a -f try.sql
SELECT
 '2020/01/07 07:20:12.718000'::TIMESTAMP AS the_ts
,extract(MONTH FROM '2020/01/07 07:20:12.718000'::TIMESTAMP) AS the_month
;
         the_ts          | the_month 
-------------------------+-----------
 2020-01-07 07:20:12.718 |         1
(1 row)
```

Or is it that you only need the time part?
Then, you need to make a timestamp out of the string using `TO_TIMESTAMP()`, and then re-format the resulting timestamp to just contain the time part, using `TO_CHAR()`:

```
WITH
input(string) AS (
  SELECT '2020/01/07 07:20:12.718000'
)
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(
    TO_TIMESTAMP(string,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
  , 'HH24:MI:SS.MS'
  )
FROM input;
   to_char    
--------------
 07:20:12.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can't actually do a direct copy from a timestamp with a non-standard format.  Here's what I did:

- Add a text column to the table to receive a text timestamp:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE dest_table ADD COLUMN timestamp_text TEXT;
  ```
- Do the copy, copying the timestamp into the text column (I used psql's `copy` command):

  ```
  \COPY dest_table(stuff,other_stuff,timestamp_text) FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV,HEADER TRUE,DELIMITER '|'
  ```
- Update the timestamp column from the text column:

  ```
  UPDATE dest_table SET the_timestamp=to_timestamp(timestamp_text,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,MS');
  ```

  (Substitute your timestamp format as appropriate)
- Drop the text timestamp column:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE dest_table DROP COLUMN timestamp_text;
  ```

Of course, you probably want to put all this into a script..